# Can I send ViewBag from controller to anther Controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I have a method called `GetPrivlidge()` that I will use it in every controller ,this method is used for what will the current logged user will see and what will not see this is the method

```
 public void GetPrivlidge()
 {
        string name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        name = EncriptionAndDecription.Encrypt(name);
        int UserId = (from c in db.users where c.Arabicusername == name select c.Usersid).SingleOrDefault();
        SamahyatOfUser S = (from SS in db.SamahyatOfUsers where SS.User_Id == UserId select SS).SingleOrDefault();
        ViewBag.Pri = S;
        string RoleName = (from R in db.Roles where R.User_ID == UserId && R.UserName == name select R.RoleName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (RoleName.Equals(EncriptionAndDecription.Encrypt("Admin")))
        {
            ViewBag.ADMIN = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ADMIN = false;
        }
 }
```

I use `ViewBag.Pri` to check in layout for privilege  ,I must send this `ViewBag` in every action so I decided to make controller that have all common methods this is my controller

```
 public class AllRequiredDataController : Controller
 {
    //
    // GET: /AllRequiredData/
    mts_exchangeEntities db = new mts_exchangeEntities();
    //this Method is used in privlidge that make user do thing and dont make anthor thing (Do or not Do)
    #region privlidge_Data
    public void GetPrivlidge()
    {
        string name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        name = EncriptionAndDecription.Encrypt(name);
        int UserId = (from c in db.users where c.Arabicusername == name select c.Usersid).SingleOrDefault();
        SamahyatOfUser S = (from SS in db.SamahyatOfUsers where SS.User_Id == UserId select SS).SingleOrDefault();
        ViewBag.Pri = S;
        string RoleName = (from R in db.Roles where R.User_ID == UserId && R.UserName == name select R.RoleName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (RoleName.Equals(EncriptionAndDecription.Encrypt("Admin")))
        {
            ViewBag.ADMIN = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ADMIN = false;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and in `_layOut` I take this `ViewBag` and make cast for in and work with privilege as this

```
FinalMts.Models.SamahyatOfUser S = (FinalMts.Models.SamahyatOfUser)ViewBag.Pri;
```

and in action I make Controller object and call the method `GetPrivlidge()` 
as this

```
 AllRequiredDataController Required = new AllRequiredDataController();
    public ActionResult AddCurrencyPrices()
    {
        //get privlidg Data
        Required.GetPrivlidge();
        return View();
    }
```

but the `layout` don't see the `ViewBag.Pri` and error message say that

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

is this controller can't see `ViewBag` if yes what should I do to deal with this `ViewBag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each controller has its own `ViewBag`. Better is to inherit your controller form `AllRequiredDataController` and use this way

```
class Controller1 : AllRequiredDataController
{
    public ActionResult AddCurrencyPrices()
    {
        //get privlidg Data
        GetPrivlidge();
        return View();
    }
}
```